# Setting application/json as the data during the dragstart in HTML5 DND

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I observed the setting the JSON data in HTML5DND will be converted into string. Are there any alternatives and best practices for passing JSON Data other than stringifying.

```js
// During drag enter
event.dataTransfer.setData('application/json', {
  id: 1
});


// During Drop data is printing as object
let data = event.dataTransfer.getData('application/json');
// printing [object Object]
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no alternative for [DataTransfer.setData()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer/setData) because its `data` (second) argument is a [DOMString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMString).

There is an alternative to DataTransfer--[DataTransferItem](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransferItem); however, using it will involve stringifying the object (to [pack that into a Blob of mimetype JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14149807/13744178)).

Comment: Thanks greg I will try it out

Answer (score 0):

In case my other answer does not answer your question, try dragging/dropping the object avatars into the textarea.

```js
const object_1 = {id: 1}
const object_2 = {id: 2}
const p_1 = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("p"))
const p_2 = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("p"))
p_1.innerText = "object_1"
p_1.draggable = true
p_2.innerText = "object_2"
p_2.draggable = true
p_1.ondragstart = function () {
    event.dataTransfer.setData("text", "object_1")
}
p_2.ondragstart = function () {
    event.dataTransfer.setData("text", "object_2")
}
const textarea = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("textarea"))
textarea.ondrop = function() {
    event.preventDefault()
    this.innerText = eval(event.dataTransfer.getData("text")).id
}
```